# output string text array but in the code dictionary array I have two strings that have the same letters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have this code where I have a dictionary array of school code to string text, but my problem I am having is the fact that my dictionary array has two values with similar text and the array is outputting both when just one exists.

```
Public Function AllocationAsString(String1)

' Parameters (Initialize)

Dim SchoolCodeOutputArr As Variant ' Temporary array that will be used to prepare the final list of school codes for output

Dim CodeDictionary As Variant ' Matches School Code to School Text Name

Dim Separator As String ' The separator between school values in the output string

Dim PrependArray As Variant ' A one-dimensional array of fields to prepend to the beginning of the string

Dim AppendArray As Variant ' A one-dimensional array of fields to append to the end of the string
    ' Parameters (Values)
SchoolCodeOutputArr = Array() ' This should be kept blank

CodeDictionary = Array( _
Array("SOA", "the School of Architecture"), _
Array("BUS", "the XXX School of Business"), _
Array("CPS", "the Center for Public Service"), _
Array("SCS", "the School of Continuing Studies"), _
Array("COW", "the Institute for Public Education Initiatives"), _
'--->SEE THESE NEXT TWO... one is "LA" and the other is "LAW"... the formula is putting the School of Law, the School of Liberal Arts when just LAW is present in the initialize string...
Array("LAW", "the School of Law"), _
Array("LA", "the School of Liberal Arts"), _
Array("MED", "the School of Medicine"), _
Array("NAM", "the XXX Art Museum"), _
Array("NCI", "the XXX College Institute"), _
Array("NTC", "the XXX Undergraduate College"), _
Array("PHTM", "the School of Public Health and Tropical Medicine"), _
Array("SSE", "the School of Science and Engineering"), _
Array("SSW", "the School of Social Work"), _
Array("ATH", "the Athletics Fund"), _
Array("LIB", "the University Library"), _
Array("MB", "the University Marching Band"), _
Array("SHIP", "Student Scholarships"), _
Array("UG", "General University Support") _
)
Separator = ", "
PrependArray = Array()
AppendArray = Array()
' Operations: Prepend
If GetArrLengthStrict(PrependArray) > -1 Then ' If PrependArray is populated, then add accordingly to the output array
' adjust the size of array
OldUBound = UBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr)
ReDim Preserve SchoolCodeOutputArr(LBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr) To (UBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr) + GetArrLengthStrict(PrependArray) + 1)) As Variant
' add prepend value(s) to the array
For i = 0 To GetArrLengthStrict(PrependArray)
SchoolCodeOutputArr(OldUBound + i + 1) = PrependArray(i)
Next
End If
' Operations: Schools from Input Fields
For i = 0 To GetArrLengthStrict(CodeDictionary) ' For each school in our dictionary
'--->I THINK THIS IS WHERE IT IS messing up...

If InStr(String1, CodeDictionary(i)(0)) Then ' If found, then adjust size of array and add school text value
ReDim Preserve SchoolCodeOutputArr(LBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr) To (UBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr) + 1)) As Variant
SchoolCodeOutputArr(UBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr)) = CodeDictionary(i)(1)
End If
Next
' Operations: Append
If GetArrLengthStrict(AppendArray) > -1 Then ' If PrependArray is populated, then add accordingly to the output array
' adjust the size of array
OldUBound = UBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr)
ReDim Preserve SchoolCodeOutputArr(LBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr) To (UBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr) + GetArrLengthStrict(AppendArray) + 1)) As Variant
' add prepend value(s) to the array
For i = 0 To GetArrLengthStrict(AppendArray)
SchoolCodeOutputArr(OldUBound + i + 1) = AppendArray(i)
Next
End If
' Operations: Change to string, and return final value
AllocationAsString = Join(SchoolCodeOutputArr, Separator) ' Combines into one string
End Function
```

So I need the code to match exactly so that when the initial string shows LAW it only outputs the School of Law... and doesn't also output liberal arts.

Comment: The code could not be tested as some functions like`GetArrLengthStrict` are not produced. and seems the objective ( as far understood)  could be achieved in simpler way. However for the basic problem may simply try `If String1 = CodeDictionary(i)(0) then` instead of `If InStr(String1, CodeDictionary(i)(0)) Then`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize there was another function that this code was referencing...

Public Function GetArrLengthStrict(var As Variant) As Integer
    GetArrLengthStrict = UBound(var) - LBound(var)
End Function

an that if statement works if there is only 1 code in the original string... but where there are two... ex allocationasstring(SSW,LIB) does not output anything because of the strict = as nowhere in my code dictionary do I have those codes combined like that.

Answer (score 0):

If what I understood is correct and your objective is to get the school names in sequence as result of the argument `String1` (which may be multiple School code separated with comma), then simply modify it like

```
' Operations: Schools from Input Fields
Dim j As Long, Xstr As String
    For j = 0 To UBound(Split(String1, ","))
    Xstr = Split(String1, ",")(j)
        For i = 0 To GetArrLengthStrict(CodeDictionary) ' For each school in our dictionary
            If Xstr = CodeDictionary(i)(0) Then ' If found, then adjust size of array and add school text value
            ReDim Preserve SchoolCodeOutputArr(LBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr) To (UBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr) + 1)) As Variant
            SchoolCodeOutputArr(UBound(SchoolCodeOutputArr)) = CodeDictionary(i)(1)
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
```

it gives output like the following for the given input argument `String1`

```
String1="LA":the School of Liberal Arts
String1="LAW":the School of Law
String1="LA,SSW,LAW":the School of Liberal Arts, the School of Social Work, the School of Law
String1="MB,LA,SSW,LAW":the University Marching Band, the School of Liberal Arts, the School of Social Work, the School of Law
String1="MB,LA,SSW,LAW,CPS":the University Marching Band, the School of Liberal Arts, the School of Social Work, the School of Law, the Center for Public Service
```